# "onLongClick" method doesn't get called for the "imageView" in the "first item" in GridView (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

> This is the sample code I am pasting here. What I actually want is to create a list of items in the MainActivity. I have used GridView for this because it is easy to set how many items do you want to get displayed in a row. Also creating spacing between them is easy.

My Objective is to open up an ArcLayout right at the position of Long Press in the ImageView in an Item of the GridView. So, I registered both OnTouchListener(to get the location of touch) and OnLongClickListener(to position the ArcLayout to that position in the event of long press).

This seems to work fine for all the items except the first item in the GridView. For some reason onLongClick method is not being called in the event of Long Press for only the "First Item" in the GridView.

This seems weird. I am not able to figure out why the "ACTION_DOWN" event is being consumed by "onTouch" for the only First Item in the GridView and not being passed to the "onLongClick method.

> Here is the link for the sample app
>   [Sample App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xmqwTW3q-3cHNUbF9ZUFJ4aVk/view?usp=sharing)
>
> You can see in the Log.d "Adapter" that LongClick is not being detected for the first item in the GridView.

**Does registering both OnTouchListener and OnLongClickListener to the same View cause any conflict?**

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> lstIds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    lstIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lstIds.add(R.drawable.img_burger);
    lstIds.add(R.drawable.img_ham_burger);
    lstIds.add(R.drawable.img_pancakes);
    lstIds.add(R.drawable.img_pizza);

    gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, lstIds);

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
}
}
```

*BaseAdapter for the GridView*

```
// GridViewAdapter.java

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {
// Instance Variables
private final String TAG = "Adapter";

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> lstImg;
private int resId;

// CONSTRUCTOR
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> lstImg) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lstImg = lstImg;
}

// Overridden Methods

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lstImg.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lstImg.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
    }


    ImageView imgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    resId = lstImg.get(position);
    imgItem.setImageResource(resId);

    // Enabling the ImageView to be Long Clickable...
    // imgItem.setLongClickable(true);

    imgItem.setOnTouchListener(this);
    imgItem.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250);
    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLongClick called...");

    Toast.makeText(context, "Long Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch ACTION_DOWN event...");
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Please do test the sample code to understand what is the problem.

Comment: **_@indramurari_** _Sir, since you have seen my code I would like to know whether you have been able to understand the problem or not._